# Passing arguments to batch file that have spaces in it

Tags: c#, batch-file

Given the following command in a batch file:

```
start /wait "" %1"Certs\makecert.exe" -n "CN="%2 -pe -ss Root -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -m 120 -a sha1 -len 2048 -r
```

You can see it expects two arguments to be passed into the batch file. The first being a folder address and the second being a subject name for the certificate being created. The problem lies in the folder address where it has a spaces in the address:  C:\Program Files (x86).

The code launching the batch file looks like:

```
private void UseBatchFile(string filePath, string parameters)
    {
        using (Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = filePath,
                Arguments = parameters,
            }
        })
        {
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

The arguments passed in would look as follows:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ TestCA"
```

The batch file will read in the C:\Program as it's first argument which resolves to

```
C:\ProgramCerts\makecert.exe
```

I have tried enclosing the string argument address in '' and using %~1 in the batch file to remove the quotes. This does not do anything either.
I cannot use %1%2%3 to creat the full address as other filepaths can be enetered into this batch file.

How can I pass in the address as one argument?

EDIT: The method is being called as follows:

```
this.UseBatchFile(string.Format("{0}{1}", PathName, @"Certs\CACert.bat"), string.Format("{0} {1}", PathName, "TestCA"));
```

PathName being : C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem is. Can you post how you're calling this method? You might also need to put the %1 *inside* the quote, but you might be getting into quote hell and security issues?

Comment: @lc. Edited the answer with how the method is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, replace this:

```
string.Format("{0}{1}", PathName, @"Certs\CACert.bat")
```

with this:

```
Path.Combine(PathName, @"Certs\CACert.bat")
```

Here is the reference for how Windows is treating those command line arguments, including numerous examples:

[Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx)

Comment: Was using the wrong combination of arguments. Passing an argument surrounded with " " and using just %1 without the ~ fixed the issue. This looked like "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\\" TestCA" in string format before being sent to the batch file.